# Prevent detection of multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, local-storage, tampermonkey, userscripts

I know it is possible to prevent the page from detecting multiple tabs if you disable javascript using chrome dev tools, replacing the "WrongPageID" with "", and then allowing javascript to run again.

I am trying to do this differently by creating a userscript, possibly requiring the use of **//@run-at document-start** in the header.

The website I'm talking about uses the code below to detect multiple tabs.

```
var thisPageID = 1e7 * Math.random();
window.addEventListener("storage", function(e) {
    console.log(e.newValue)
    "RecentPageID" == e.key && e.newValue != thisPageID && localStorage.setItem("WrongPageID", e.newValue), "WrongPageID" == e.key && e.newValue ==
        thisPageID && (document.location = "/Player/Error/Duplicate")
}), localStorage.setItem("RecentPageID", thisPageID);
```